# Laptop Screen Flickers even after using Proprietary diver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

I have Asus tuf Fx505dt here are specifications:
                AMD® Ryzen 5 3550h with radeon vega mobile gfx × 8 and GeForce Gtx 1650 .
The screen flickers continuously after logging again from sleep . This was asked earlier in stack exchange.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559506/kubuntu-19-10-screen-flickers-after-waking-up-from-suspend-mode

Since no one answered yet so I am asking it here again to highlight this issue again.

Comment: What OS/Version are you running?

Comment: I am on ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 1):

hey i have the same issue.. well its the display issue, drivers can properly adjust the display clock speeds thats why it starts flickering.
well there is a temproray solution that ive found
use this command

```
xset dpms force off
```

use this command until the flicker stops

you join the support chat on telegram => @asustuf